# Model to concatenate strings get overwritten

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

New to MVC here, so apologies for what may be a silly question.

I have created some database-first entity framework models for an existing database, which is working great. One of the models pulls out a first and last name from the database, which i can reference in my code.

```
namespace manage.mysite.com.DataModels
{
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;

    public partial class UserProfile
    {
        [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2214:DoNotCallOverridableMethodsInConstructors")]
        public UserProfile()
        {
            this.webpages_Roles = new HashSet<webpages_Roles>();
            this.Property_Info = new HashSet<Property_Info>();
        }

        public string Email { get; set; }
        public int UserId { get; set; }
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        public string LastName { get; set; }
        public string TelNumber { get; set; }


        [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
        public virtual ICollection<webpages_Roles> webpages_Roles { get; set; }
        [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
        public virtual ICollection<Property_Info> Property_Info { get; set; }
    }
}
```

I then added another string under lastName, to tie them together:

```
public string FullName { 
    get
    {
        return FirstName + " " + LastName;
    }
}
```

This works absolutely perfectly, except the problem that every time i need to update the model from the database, this obviously get's overwritten. How do i stop this from happening?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`NotMapped`](http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/code-first/notmapped-dataannotations-attribute-in-code-first.aspx) attribute:

```
[NotMapped]
public string FullName { 
    get
    {
        return FirstName + " " + LastName;
    }
}
```

That is using [Data Annotations](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj591583.aspx). If you prefer [Fluent Api](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj591617.aspx#1.6) then it would be this way:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<UserProfile>().Ignore(t => t.FullName);
```

### Update

Use a partial class to avoid losing your custom properties every time you update your model from the DB:

```
public partial class UserProfile
{
  [NotMapped]
  public string FullName { 
    get
    {
        return FirstName + " " + LastName;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: This worked perfections. I needed to reference the System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema and it's all good now. thanks

Comment: Actually, i was mistaken, it still get's removed when i refresh the model from the database. Any ideas? Should i move this to a seperate model?

Comment: Now I noticed you are working with an existing database, yes, in that case use a partial class to add custom properties like this one

Comment: In the same model yes?

Comment: that's right, add the partial class in the same project where you have your entity classes.